# How to get GenieACS running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, mongodb, redis, easycwmp

I am trying to install and work with GenieACS (an openSource auto configuration server). I followed  [this instructions](https://tr069.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/installing-genieacs-on-precise-pangolin/comment-page-1/#comment-649) and was able to successfully install it. I need to bring that tool now to life and make the first connection with a CPE. Is there someone who is already working with GenieACS and can tell me which files should i modify (where/how) in order to get GenieACS running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is too broad to be answered here. Even the guide you followed is outdated(!)

I wrote a guide (It's going to be outdated in some months, I'm currently developing the new one for Debian 8) but you can still use it.

The working guide is here: https://github.com/zaidka/genieacs/wiki/GenieACS-v1.1.x-installation-in-Ubuntu-14.04-Server